# UITableView cellForRowAt vs willDisplay

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I'm a little frustrated. I have a iOS 10 project `UITableView` with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` cells. I set constraints properly.

Initially I was mapping my cells inside

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

and everything was working fine, but then I read an article: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.4rnbc4vyg and moved my data mapping to

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

after this my auto layout cells stopped to work properly.

My understanding that at height is calculating after `cellForRowAt` but before `willDisplay`, so when I'm mapping in `willDisplay` height is already set for my cell and I need to reload it again (which is not good).

Anyone can proof/explain this?

**UPDATE:**

After posting a question, I found this article: https://tech.zalando.com/blog/proper-use-of-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willdisplaycell/

Comment: You could mark my response below as answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always set up your cell inside `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Apple documentation says about **cellForRowAt**:

> Asks the data source for a cell to insert in a particular location of the table view.

[tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview)

**willDisplay** on the other can be used to override certain properties of a cell just before it is drawn to view. I would suggest if you are not sure about willDisplay just do all your set up in cellForRowAt.

Apple's doc says about willDisplay:

> This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color.

More on willDisplay is here in Apple's documentation:
[tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview?language=objc)

**EDIT**: After reading the link you provided - I reaffirm that unless you really have a specific reason to setup your cell in **willDisplayCell**, just do it in **cellForRowAt**.